# Why does the LicenseRegistry in flutter return a Stream<LicenseEntry> and not a List<LicenseEntry>?

Tags: flutter, licensing, flutter-dependencies

I would like to unterstand why `LicenseRegistry.licenses` returns `Stream<LicenseEntry>` and not `List<LicenseEntry>`? Wouldn't a simple list make more sense here instead of a Stream?

The dart documentation states a Stream as the following:

> A Stream provides a way to receive a sequence of events. Each event is
>   either a data event, also called an element of the stream, or an error
>   event, which is a notification that something has failed. When a
>   stream has emitted all its event, a single "done" event will notify
>   the listener that the end has been reached.

Can maybe anyone explain the relationship between a List of licenses and the description of a Stream?

The flutter documentation states that `LicenseRegistry.licenses` is an expensive operation. 
Is the fact that it returns a Stream correlated to that?

Sources:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-async/Stream-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/LicenseRegistry/licenses.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A stream is useful (as here) when partial results are useful to the consumer. In this case the normal consumer is the `LicensePage` widget. It listens to the stream using `await for` and as it gets each package's licenses it adds them to the page with a `setState`. In this way it can begin to render the final page as work continues to deliver more licenses. (The `await for` loop terminates if the widget is unmounted while it is still in progress, so that the rest of the page isn't formatted and rendered if the license page is closed.)

If, instead, the return value were a list, that list would have to be built before the first license could be rendered.

In an interesting twist, the `LicensePage` widget has to extract the paragraphs from each `LicenseEntry` which are delivered by an iterable. It converts them to a list in a background task! So, it processes each set of paragraphs from a particular entry in a group.

```
  final List<LicenseParagraph> paragraphs =
    await SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleTask<List<LicenseParagraph>>(
      license.paragraphs.toList,
      Priority.animation,
      debugLabel: 'License',
    );
```

Comment: Well explained! Thank you.